# Mysql: procedure + trigger on INSERT in one flow

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

1) I have some table `programs`.

2) I have **PROCEDURE** for changing in this table:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE update_lessons_ord (IN courseId INT)
    BEGIN
            SET @ord :=0;
                UPDATE programs mcp_1
                    INNER JOIN programs mcp_2 ON mcp_1.id = mcp_2.id
                        SET mcp_1.ord = ( @ord := @ord +1 )
                            WHERE mcp_2.course_id = courseId;
    END;
```

3) I have first **TRIGGER** (delete):

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `update_lessons_ord_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `programs`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        CALL update_lessons_ord(OLD.course_id);
    END;
```

It works Ok!

4) I have second **TRIGGER** (insert):

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `update_lessons_ord_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `programs`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        CALL update_lessons_ord(NEW.course_id);
    END;
```

It works wrong: "**Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger**".

How can I use my **PROCEDURE** in this situation?

Comment: Can you post the code of the stored procedure?

Comment: In both cases the error is generated, here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af25ec/2) example.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger